# How do I prevent a duplicate entry for a Create/Edit Functionality in ASP.NET Core w/ EF?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, razor, duplicates, crud

I am trying to prevent a user from creating a form with a FirstName, LastName, and DOB that match an entry in the database and editing a form to match an existing entry. If you could also lead me to how I can show an error when this happens, that would be awesome.

My Model:

```
public class MRegForm
{
    public int MRegFormId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
```

[I tried Index attribute. It did not work for me. I was able to create new duplicate forms with no issues.

```
[Index(nameof(FirstName), nameof(LastName), nameof(DOB), IsUnique = true)]
public class MRegForm
{
```

I also tried this. Same thing.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelbuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelbuilder);

        modelbuilder.Entity<MRegForm>()
            .HasIndex(x => new { x.FirstName, x.LastName, x.DOB})
            .IsUnique();

    }

    public DbSet<MRegForm> MRegForm { get; set; } = default!;
```

I think that there is maybe a way to prevent this in the OnPostAsync()

This is my create OnPostAsync():

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        MRegForm.CreatorId = UserManager.GetUserId(User);

        var isAuthorized = await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, MRegForm, RegFormOperations.Create);

        if (isAuthorized.Succeeded == false)
            return Forbid();

        Context.MRegForm.Add(MRegForm);
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

This is my Edit OnPostAsync():

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int id)
    {
        var mRegForm = await Context.MRegForm.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.MRegFormId == id);

        if (mRegForm == null)
            return NotFound();

        MRegForm.CreatorId = mRegForm.CreatorId;

        var isAuthorized = await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, MRegForm, RegFormOperations.Update);

        if (isAuthorized.Succeeded == false)
            return Forbid();

        MRegForm.Status = mRegForm.Status; // the Status is the current Status - Do Not Reset

        Context.Attach(MRegForm).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!MRegFormExists(MRegForm.MRegFormId))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }

    private bool MRegFormExists(int id)
    {
      return (Context.MRegForm?.Any(e => e.MRegFormId == id)).GetValueOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: The attribute and the `HasIndex` method only serve migrations, they don't add any client-side validation. In other words: the index must be added to the database, either manually or by a new migration. On top of that, in order to prevent ugly database exceptions, you should add the client-side validation yourself. The index is the final catch that may fire if there's a lot of concurrency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to download the entity from the database if exists and make changes to it or creating new one if not exist.
Your clients can always make new `MRegForm` in the form, but you add or update in the back and. Bether option will be to pass the existing `MRegForm` to the form and the client see and change all props he need.

```
public async Task AddOrUpdate(MRegForm input)
{

   var mRegForm = await Context.MRegForm
      .FirstOrDefaltAsync(x => x.FirstName == input.FirstName && x.LastName == input.LastName && x.DOB == input.YourDate);

   if(mRegForm != null)
   {
       //Make changes on mRegForm

       mRegForm.SomeProp = input.SomeProp,
       ...
   }
   else
   {
       var newMRegForm = new MRegForm
       {
          //Set all props you need
       }

       await this.Context.AddAsync(newMRegForm );
   }

   await this.Context.SaveCangesAsync();

}
```